# Check if any row is selected in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to write a function to check if any of the table rows are selected.

I need this function to be triggered at any `<tr>` click.

Thank you.

Here is my code for selecting rows:

```
$('#Request tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
          $(this).removeClass('selected');
     } else {
          oTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
     }
});
```

Comment: What is your problem and where is your HTML? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It should work according to: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Answer (score 13):

As of Datatables 1.10, there is an any() method that can be used:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

if ( table.rows( '.selected' ).any() )
    // Your code here
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks @corpico

Answer (score 1):

You have answer in your question already. The code below would let you determine if there are any selected rows.

```
var $rows = oTable.$('tr.selected');

// If some rows are selected
if($rows.length){

// Otherwise, if no rows are selected
} else {

}
```

I assume that somewhere in your code you have `var oTable = $('#Request').DataTable()`. Otherwise you can use `$('#Request').DataTable()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = $('#foo-table').DataTable();
var selectedRows = table.rows({ selected: true });
```

This is proper way to get the selected rows as of DataTables 1.10.8.

Answer (score 0):

Using the API.

```
var oTable = $("#yourtable").DataTable();

anyRowSelected = oTable.rows({selected : true}).indexes().length === 0 ? false : true;//false - nothing selected. true - 1 or more are selected.
```